# SwiftSuspenders not working like it should?

Tags: actionscript-3, null, swiftsuspenders

I'm just getting my feet wet with trying to use swift suspenders for an AS3 project but my injections are null when I try to access them. It only works when I use injector.injectInto() explicitly to inject into the object that should have a reference. But that can't be the optimal approach with SwiftSuspenders, right?

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you by any change accessing your injected properties in class constructor? If so, use `PostConstruct` meta.

```
public class Example
{
    [Inject] public var foo:Bar;

    public function Example()
    {
        foo.barMe(); // throws null reference error
    }

    [PostConstruct]
    public function _postConstruct():void
    {
        foo.barMe(); // OK
    }
}
```

> **PostConstruct: Automatically invoking methods on injection
>   completion**
>
> Instances of classes that depend on
>   automatic DI are only ready to be used
>   after the DI has completed. Annotating
>   methods in the injectee class with the
>   [PostConstruct] metadata causes them
>   to be invoked directly after all
>   injections have completed and it is
>   safe to use the instance. Multiple
>   methods can be invoked in a defined
>   order by using the order parameter:
>   [PostConstruct(order=1)].

[ref [1]](https://github.com/tschneidereit/SwiftSuspenders)

Answer (score 0):

You *do* need to call `injectInto` on every object requiring dependencies. The way around this step is to abstract that step into a dependency injection container (*"DI container"*) that manages that for you. The MVC toolkit, [Robotlegs](http://www.robotlegs.org/), accomplishes this with its own system for automated dependency injection.

Here's an excerpt from the "ActionScript Developer's Guide to Robotlegs":

> The intention behind automated DI containers is to abstract the
>   fulfillment of dependencies from the application itself. Essentially,
>   we split this job out completely, so that the application code no
>   longer has to do it, and instead we ask a third party—the DI
>   container—to get it done.